# PyAudio on MacOS with minconda virtual environment runtime issue with import

Tags: pyaudio, portaudio

So I have this namespace error on a symbol not found in flat namespace. I've read other posts about this mentioning that it has to do with the underlying library and how those files are complied in C++. Please let me know if there is a way that I can fix this.
I tried researching online about how to fix this, I've read pretty much every relevant stack overflow post, tried reinstalling portaudio using brew and pyaudio, tried down versioning both libraries to see if they would work to no avail.

Thank you!

````
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/nikhileshbelulkar/opt/miniconda3/envs/fingers_crossed/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nikhileshbelulkar/opt/miniconda3/envs/fingers_crossed/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'```
````